# How to configure deploy_contract for fork Pancakeswap

Tags: ethereum, solidity, binance, binance-smart-chain

I woudlike to fork pancakeswap on binance smart chain :

I have actually this contracts :

```
Caketoken.sol
SyrupBar.sol
MasterChef.sol
Migrations.sol
Timelock.sol
```

How can I specify the 2_deploy_contract.js to deploy each of this token ?

```
const CakeToken = artifacts.require("CakeToken");
const SyrupBar = artifacts.require("SyrupBar");
const MasterChef = artifacts.require("MasterChefV2");
let admin = "adress 0X"

module.exports = function(deployer) {
  // 1st deployment
  deployer.deploy(CakeToken).then(function() {
    return deployer.deploy(SyrupBar, CakeToken.address).then(function() {
      return deployer.deploy(MasterChef, CakeToken.address, SyrupBar.address, admin, "1000000000000000000", 4021488)
    })
  })
};
```

Comment: Voting to close this question, as the scope of this question is too wide and needs a generic answer "How to deploy smart contracts". It is tutorial topic and covered elsewhere.

Comment: you can deploy by following the steps;
1. deploy cake
2. deploy syrup
3. deploy master chef
4. transfer the ownership of cake to masterchef
5. transfer the ownership of syrup to masterchef
6. transfer the ownership of masterchef to timelock